# Finding dim(span(s)) Using a Basis

Tags: matrices

I need to find the question for this answer.

Use the Simplified Span Method to find a simplified general form for all the vectors(basis) in $\mathrm{span} (S)$, where 
$$S=\{ [1,2,3,-1,0] ,[3,6,8,-2,0], [-1,-1,-3,1,1], [-2,-3,-5,1,1]\}$$ and find $\dim(\mathrm{span}(S))$  using this basis.

I found the basis of $\mathrm{span}(S)$ as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2gKY.png)

Comment: What is your question?  You have found a basis for the span... now what?  All you are left with is deciding what the dimension is?  All you need to do for that is to check how many vectors were used in the basis...

Comment: What is the “Simplified Span Method?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! now, if you calculated right, then $dim (Sp { S})=3$